# postgres data to dashing

Tags: sinatra, dashing

Is it possible to send data contained in postgres to dashing dashboard? I have found mysql example [here](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/How-to:-send-mysql-data-to-your-widgets) and same question [here](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/564).

I edited my job in jobs folder. I have also included **pg** gem.

```
require 'pg'
conn = PGconn.new(:host => "10.10.8.10", :port => "5432",:dbname => "db1",:login => "test",:password => "test")
results  = conn.exec("select partner,sitetype from test")
# Sending to List widget, so map to :label and :value
  acctitems = results.map do |row|
    row = {
      :label => row['partner'],
      :value => row['sitetype']
    }
  end

  # Update the List widget
  send_event('account_count', { items: acctitems } )

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include in Gemfile :

```
gem 'pg'
```

In your jobs.rb file:

```
require 'pg'

SCHEDULER.every '3m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
conn = PGconn.new(:host => "localhost", :port => "5432",:dbname => "dbname",:user => "test",:password => "test")
results  = conn.exec("select partner,sitetype from test")
# Sending to List widget, so map to :label and :value
  acctitems = results.map do |row|
    row = {
      :label => row['partner'],
      :value => row['sitetype']
    }
  end

  # Update the List widget
  send_event('account_count', { items: acctitems } )

end
```